# Mobiscroll datetime, remove all validation

Tags: mobiscroll

I'm prototyping this date picker with a client. They are finding it very confusing that you need to pick year first before other months and days become available for selection (which is fair enough).

We do date validation on the backened anyway, so is there anyway to remove the disabling of invalid dates so the user can choose anything they want immediately, instead of following the required pattern of year -> month -> day selections.

I couldn't find anything in the docs.

Comment: Please post some code on how are you initializing the datepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by not including maxDate, even if it was null